# Invalid Hostname error in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, hostname

I'm a novice in scrapy and I have trouble.  When scrapy make request downloading from:

> http://cache.pack.google.com/edgedl/earth/client/GE7/release_7_1_2/GoogleEarth-Win-Bundle-7.1.2.2041.1.exe

I get an error:

> twisted.python.failure.Failure exceptions.ValueError: invalid
>   hostname: r2---sn-ug5onuxaxjvh-n8vs.c.pack.google.com

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does it happen all the time? I was able to reproduce it one using `scrapy shell "http://cache.pack.google.com/edgedl/earth/client/GE7/release_7_1_2/GoogleEarth-Win-Bundle-7.1.2.2041.1.exe"`, but now it's working for me.

Comment: I'm using Srapy 1.3.3 and it happen always, using you command too

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this. Can you share a more complete console log?

Answer (score 9):

You need to put http address in *inverted comma*.
As mentioned [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project) for linux you can put address in single inverted commas '', but for windows users "" might work.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you must use double inverted quotes ("url-path") instead of single inverted quote('url-path').

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data